# Pentaho Security: how to implement SSO with CAS

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, cas, pentaho

i tried to implement SSO with pentaho based on this example: http://blog.datamensional.com/2011/07/pentaho-sso-setup-using-cas-and-ldap/ but i have some issues. i am using pentaho 4 and i want to change authentication datasource to  mysql tables and tell pentaho to use them for authentication

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked here:

http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/topic/security_guide/task_auth_cas_sso.html?resultof=%22%73%73%6f%22%20

Or just search for "sso" on infocenter..

Comment: this is for an enterprise version i am using the community edition

Comment: still applies - it's the same code/method.  Check in the IRC channel then on ##freenode - lots of people have done this, someone will help you!